# How to get the type/ID of the icon set used for Conditional Formatting in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm new to Excel and VBA. I have a worksheet in which I have applied Conditional Formatting to a range of cells using icon sets. I need to get the **ID of the icon set**, so that I can check if a specific icon set is used in the worksheet using VBA.
I was able to change the icon set of the range E2:E10 using:

```
Dim rg As Range
Dim iset As IconSetCondition
Set rg = Range("E2:E10")
rg.FormatConditions.Delete
Set iset = rg.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
iset.IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3TrafficLights1)
```

I was able to retrieve the icon set's integer ID using:

```
iconID = iset.IconSet.ID
' This returned 4, which corresponds to xl3TrafficLights1
```

What I need is to be able to retrieve the ID of the icon set that is already applied to a range of cells, so that I can compare it with a specific ID.
Something like this:

```
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range("E2:E10")

iconID = rg.IconSet.ID ' ==> This is what I need

If iconID = 4 Then
    MsgBox ("Success")
Else
    MsgBox ("Failed")
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why but the code below appears to return the number you want.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim iCon As IconSetCondition

Set Rng = Cells(2, 1)
Set iCon = Rng.FormatConditions(1)
Debug.Print iCon.IconSet.ID
```

Note that it will fail if Rng doesn't have a CF [involving an icon set] set.